# How do I change my @ubuntu.com email alias?

Tags: email, ubuntu-email-address

I have an ubuntu.com email address which was aliased to an email account I no longer use (or own). I'd like to point to to my gmail account now.

Who maintains these aliases or is there a way for me to change it myself?

Answer (score 10):

Your `@ubuntu.com` email address forwards email to the contact address associated with your Launchpad account, as described here:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuEmail

You can select a different contact address or register additional email addresses to your account at the following page:

https://launchpad.net/~/+editemails